# python selenium: how to get first hidden button's url?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

The page that I worked on has invisible hidden option button.

```
* download sample video in the page(button is hidden by html)
[button1] (<- LINK_TEXT i s 'button1')
[button2]
[button3]
```

so, I used 'EC.element_to_be_clickable'.
This code is working, but this way can not used if I don't know button's LINK_TEXT. The name of LINK_TEXT is different for each page.

I want to get only video's first link url(ex- button1).

```
_sDriver = webdriver.Firefox()
_sDriver.get('www.example.com/video')

wait = WebDriverWait(_sDriver, 10)
download_menu = _sDriver.find_element_by_id("download-button")
action = ActionChains(_sDriver)
action.move_to_element(download_menu).perform()

documents_url = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "button1"))).get_attribute('href')
```

my code's result is gotten by url of 'button1', but if I don't know 'button1' text, how to get first hidden button's url using python?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by "button" I assume you mean `a` element in this case.

And, since the button is hidden, `element_to_be_clickable` would not work, use `presence_of_element_located`. To get the very first `a` element, use the "by tag name" locator:

```
documents_url = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a"))).get_attribute('href')
```

There could be a better way to locate the element, without seeing the actual HTML of the mentioned "button" elements, it is difficult to tell.